# Is it illegal to use $ dollar to indicate in game currencies?

Tags: united-states, currency

I'm creating a game where the player earns money while playing, my question is, could it be considered illicit or misleading to use the dollar sign ($) after the current amount of money in-game. I'm releasing the app on the Play Store, so I was wondering if I could get trouble in for using the sign even while the in-game currency is not in any way bound to real-world money. I haven't added in-game purchases so it's completely detached. 
My main concern would be the legality in the countries where the dollar sign is used, for example, the US and Australia. 
Is it illegal or should I fear any type of legal repercussion?

Comment: I don't think the symbol has any legal status.  It's used not only in countries that call their currency "dollar," but also in those that call their currency "peso" (except for the Philippines, if Wikipedia is to be believed).  So you have a good number of countries to check with before embarking on this project.

Comment: It's not illegal and you won't face any charges, it's a Unicode standard symbol present in almost any modern computing system and has no copyright nor legal value whatsoever, just like #, @ and so goes on. What hold the validity of the currency is your contract with your users. While the $ symbol is used to represent currency, from a game design standpoint you should design your own currency, like R$(Roblox Dollars) or L$(Linden Dollars from Second Life), and you should explicitate on your ToS that your currency is not attached in any way with real world currency.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc Don't answer in the comments.